# automated creation of folder and subfolder(subfolder linked to userid)

Tags: php, .htaccess

Creating of folder and subfolder(linked to database userid.The subfolder is not being created where images of the user will be deployed.The images should beplaced in the userid folder when the user yploads it.Please if anyone can help and give coding for it relative to my coding please.Here is the code below

```
session_start();

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  
$storeFolder = '../../advertiser_images/'.str_replace("#","",$_SESSION["userID"]);   



if (!empty($_FILES)) 
{
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                 
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; 
    $targetFile =  $targetPath.$_SESSION["vid"].str_replace(" ","",$_FILES['file']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
include_once '../../modules/database/db-functions.php'; 

$data = array();

$data[0] = 'booklook';
$data[1] = 'book_images';
$data[2] = 'vid';
$data[3] = '#'.$_SESSION["vid"];
$data[4] = 'did';
$data[5] = $_SESSION["userID"];
$data[6] = 'iid';
$data[7] = $_SESSION["vid"].str_replace(" ","",$_FILES['file']['name']);
$data[8] = 'img_loc';
$data[9] = 'advertiser_images/'.str_replace("#","",$_SESSION["userID"]).'/'.$_SESSION["vid"].str_replace(" ","",$_FILES['file']['name']);

add($data);
```

Comment: What you have tried so far .

Comment: Well im not sure where the fault is so I haven't tried much to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing directory creation in your code:

```
$path = realpath('../../advertiser_images').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.str_replace("#", "", $_SESSION["userID"]);

if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0755, true);
}
```

Functions man:
[`realpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) - get real path from relative path also fixing directory separators,
[`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) - checks if dir/file exists
[`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) - create directory. First argument is dir name, second - dir mode and third - create recursively (mean that parent dirs also will be created)